# Oracle sql dynamically update a column when another column from another table is updated from a user through a client server web site

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, oracle

Please can anyone help me?
I created a database for a factory. I am stuck at the point where the quantity of a particular product could be updated from an order from a new customer (on a website i think with get method from php). 
To make it clear.. I was thinking to have:

`Product(code,name,value,quantity available)`,

`Order(ordernumber,productcode,quantity needed)`

So if someone order 2 items of the same product code and the factory manufacture those 2 items how can we see this change automatically done in the database, before and after. Also how can we accept value of 0 when the factory has no item of a particular product (by counting)? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like things you can resolve with tryggers...

Comment: Do you have any code to show. Maybe then, we can help you more.

Comment: How can you see the change automatically done? Surely you just look in the database on the particular order number for the product code you are interested in?

Comment: I am thinking about triggers too.
But how?
I don't have any code. Only the tables of the database..

My problem is specifically that : "for each product there is a need to 
record its product name and the total number of items (which may be zero) of that 
product held by the company. It is important that the number of items of each 
product stocked at a particular factory is accurately recorded."

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a work for a trigger

take a look to this examples on how to deal with triggers::

[An Introduction to Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)

[Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)